# In vuforia model target using unity how to adjust the dimensions of the model?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

Hi I was developing a simple model target for testing.I uploaded the cad data which is .obj file into the vuforia model target generator.After generating the target ,I imported the package  into unity.Initially I did not adjust in the dimensions in the inspector.The guide view was so small.The object was not tracked.So in the inspector I adjusted the physical length,width and height and  guide view mode to guide view 2 D .When I took the build in device still the the guide view was so small . Original (Physical) dimensions of the model is 10 cm x 5 cm x 5 cm.How to adjust the correct dimensions in unity according to Physical model measurements.I am using SAMSUNG S7 .We can test model target only using Android devices?

[image: modeltarget-generator view,Inspector-view and mobile out view]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the size of the guide view then you simply have to zoom in before you select the detection position in the model target generator. If you want to change the dimensions of the model itself, it's better to resize it in your 3D/CAD software before you open it with the model target generator. The generater only allows you to choose how to interpret the units of your model (cm,mm,m, inch, feet).